# contar items en node js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

hola buenos días estoy necesitando ayuda para contar items en node js.

Yo recupero un json desde un pagina que es algo así:
[{"ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","puerto":"xxxx","gid":"2","active":"2","queryport":"xxxx"},{"ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","puerto":"xxxxx","gid":"3","active":"2","queryport":"xxxx"},{"ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","puerto":"xxxxx","gid":"2","active":"1","queryport":"xxxx"}]

y en node js tengo un código así.

```
var obj = {table: []};
var obj = JSON.parse(body);
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i) {
if (obj[i].gid == "2"){
hago lo que necesito.
}
```

El tema es que no encuentro la forma de contar los "gid" en este caso habría 2, ya que el otro no es = a 2.
A alguien sabe que metodo se puede implementar para contarlo?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [`reduce( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) presente en los *array*:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(body);

console.log( obj.reduce( function( acu, item ) { 
  return acu + ( 'gid' in item && item.gid === '2' );
}, 0 ) );
```

Este ejemplo contaría las apariciones de elementos cuyo `gid === 2`.

- `gid in item` para comprobar que el elemento tiene un campo `gid` (*porsi*).
- `item.gid === '2'` solo tiene en cuenta los elementos **exactamente iguales** a `'2'`, sin *coherción* de tipos.
- `return acu + ( ... )` toda expresión *booleana* se transforma implícitamente a `0` si es `false` o a `1` si es `true`, con lo que nos ahorramos código: si no existe, se retorna `acu + 0`. Si existe, se retorna `acu + 1`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, con esto pude resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

puede ser alguno de los siguientes problemas, por cierto recuerda usar identación.

```js
var body = [
    {ip:"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",puerto:"xxxx",gid:"2",active:"2",queryport:"xxxx"},
    {ip:"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",puerto:"xxxx",gid:"3",active:"2",queryport:"xxxx"},
    {ip:"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",puerto:"xxxx",gid:"2",active:"1",queryport:"xxxx"}
]
var obj = {table: []}; // este elemento se vuelve a definir abajo por lo que deja de tener esta forma de objeto cuidado con eso
var obj = body;//obvie el json parse para usar directamente los objetos js, si no funciona el codigo lo mas probable es que aqui sea la falla

//fragmento editado
var counter = {} // aqui almacenas las apariciones de cada gid

for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { //el for usa post-increment osea i++ envez de ++i para empezar desde el comienzo el array
  console.log(counter);//muestra el counter antes de hacer un cambio
  if (counter[`${obj[i].gid}`] >= 1) {
    counter[`${obj[i].gid}`]++; //añade 1 si el gid existe en counter
  } else {
    counter[`${obj[i].gid}`] = 1;// si no existe lo inicializa con un valor por defecto en 1
  }
  console.log(counter);//muestra el counter despues de un cambio
}//cerramos el for
//y para acceder al las veces que aparece es muy simple solo has lo siguiente:
counter['2']
//ejemplo
console.log(counter['2'])
```

Comment: ¿Y en qué parte tu código cuenta los elementos repetidos?